# import variableName vs const variableName while importing library in typescript

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

I am writing chai-mocha tests in typescript

```
import * as chai from 'chai'
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')

chai.use(chaiHttp)
...
await chai.request('http://localhost:' + config.expressPort)
```

The above code throws an error `Property 'request' does not exist on type 'ChaiStatic'`

But if I change the way chai-http is imported like this

```
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
```

The code runs successfully.

I have never imported any library like this. I would like to know what exactly is happening here.

P.S.: this is my test script:
`mocha --require ts-node/register test/test.spec.ts -t 5000 --exit`

**Note**: after @types/chai-http is installed and then `import * as chaiHttp from 'chai-http'` code is added , then I get the error `resolved into a non-module entity and cannot be imported from this construct`

Comment: You should be using `import * as chaiHttp from 'chai-http';`, neither of the solutions you have.

Comment: this throws an error even if @types is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `@types/chai-http` installed, `import chaiHttp = require('chai-http')` is [a special syntax recognized by TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) to import a CommonJS module that uses an export assignment.  As an import, it causes TypeScript to load the `chai-http` type declarations, which include an augmentation that makes `chai.request` work.  In `const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')`, `require('chai-http')` is treated as an ordinary function call that does not cause TypeScript to load the `chai-http` type declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code locally and got same error for either using const and import statement.

```
Property 'request' does not exist on type 'ChaiStatic'.
```

However, the generated js should be same. Looking at js file, it is generated as

```
var chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
```

So the issue is happened in compile time from TS to JS. To solve it, I installed `@types/chai-http`

```
npm install @types/chai-http --save-dev
```